# Cannot redirect from Chrome extension's background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In `Ajax's done() method` I have to redirect to `download.php?file=filename.txt` which will force a download of the given file. The problem is that `window.location` is not working.

What I've tried is:

```
window.location = "http://domain.com/download.php?file=test.txt";
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'window.location = "http://domain.com/download.php?file=test.txt"' });
```

Both doesn't work. I thought that it may be from the Ajax (I red something about redirecting on success) and tried these outside (and before) the Ajax code. Not working again.

Part from **manifest.json:**

```
...
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "scripts/jquery.min.js",
        "scripts/background.js"
    ]
},
...
```

When trying from a external file `window.location` is working, the problem is when it's used in the extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using [`chrome.downloads`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html), or [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-update).

Comment: @RobW, I prefer to use `chrome.downloads` but it's not working. Here is my question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187792/how-to-use-dev-channels-features-chrome-downloads-on-a-published-chrome-exten Will take a look on `chrome.tabs.update` now.

Comment: @RobW, thank you for `chrome.tabs.update`. It worked. If you write an answer I will accept it. By the way, I still prefer using `downloads` (see the comment above), do you have some idea for it? Or I just have to wait for new versions of Chrome which will support this API on a stable channel?